# SVG linearGradient doesn't works in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, reactjs, svg, gradient

SVG linearGradient gradient doesn't work for me in firefox.
I use SVG in `React.Component` so I've converted SVG to jsx.
The first problem was that converter kills camel case on "linearGradient" so I fixed that.
 Now gradient works in all browsers but not in safari.
Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61525/ 
I saw similar topics in stackoverflow but it didn't help me.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How to cope with that?

**UPDATE** 
I found the solution (workaround) for this issue, but I still don't understand why this defect is appeared.

 If i put styles for svg directly in head styles: 
 
`...
<head>
  <style>
    svg styles
  </style>
</head>
...` 
 Everything works fine. But if I put this styles into separete `.scss` file. that is loaded by webpack-loader the linearGradient stops work.

Comment: It's displaying fine for me in Safari 10. I thought that Illustrator generated markup would give me cancer, so I cleaned it up. Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/n5aa6qxe/

Comment: Yes I did. So, you tell me that in this case when a browser sees url(#anid) the browser would not seek this reference on the page? But it works in chrome and edge. To be honest I didn't read about local references in css specification, but I don't see reason why it wouldn't works.

Comment: The specification has changed recently, the change has been implemented in Firefox and is working its way through to release.